# How to find X axis value against peak value of signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, signal-processing

I need help in finding value at x-axis against the peak value found.

Is there any way I can directly plot a line by looking at peak value because this command gives me peak location and value on y –axis but unfortunately my x-axis is not defined in good way.

Because I also used x_max_value = x(indexes) but it is not giving me correct value.

I want to find out the difference in values of x-axis of 2 peaks first and 3rd peak. That’s why I need this.

How to find X axis value against peak found in signal.

I have tried these commands but unfortunately did not worked.

```
           x_at = x( firstpeak_1_loc)
           x_at = x( lastpeak_1_loc)


     %     ind = find(f== lastpeak_2);
      %     x(ind)
```

So that’s why I want to draw a line directly under the peak to get x axis value clearly.

```
     X = [2 3 4 5 10 7 8 9 5 6 ];
     Plot(x)
    [pks,locs] = findpeaks(x)
```

Is it possible for me to draw a vertical line at a point where I find peak value against x axis because I have issue with values of x axis?

I want to find out the difference in values of x-axis of 2 peaks first and 3rd peak. That’s why I need this .

Comment: yes in this it is also explained how to do the stuff i needed sorry but i remained unable to find this post may be due to search selection criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the index of the peak in 'locs', and if you want to order the peaks, use sort option in 'findpeaks':

```
clear;
y = [2 3 4 5 10 7 8 15 5 6 ];
N=length(y);
x=linspace(-6,4,N); % the data must contain x for each y

[y_atpeak,locs] = findpeaks(y,'SortStr','descend');
x_atpeak = x(locs);

plot(x,y,'r-',x_atpeak,y_atpeak,'go')

if length(y_atpeak)>=1
    Yhighest=y_atpeak(1)
end
if length(y_atpeak)>=2
    Ysecond=y_atpeak(2)
end
```

Comment: Mendi Barel is it also possible for me to find 2nd largest peak means for first peak i have   firstpeak_1 = pks(1) but what is command for 2nd peak.

Comment: Look at answer. you need to use special command to order the peaks.